# Image Capturing Not Working iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 2 view controller `RootViewController` & `CameraViewController`.
In CameraViewController:

```
- (IBAction) takePhoto: (id) sender
{
   [root.camera takePicture];
}
```

Here 'root' is an instance of `RootViewController` & 'camera' is an instance of `UIImagePickerController` & 'takePicture' is the default method of iOS to capture image. Other delegate methods for `UIImagePickerController` is set. But the problem is no picture is taken by the event! I cant understand where is the problem happening. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should present camera first then take photo as per below:

```
[self presentViewController:root.camera animated:YES completion:^{
      [root.camera takePicture];
}];
```

Note that you need to dismiss the camera in your delegate methods.

Comment: is the camera presented, or it stays invisible ? check the updated answer